# Hybrid(?) graphics card in Linux

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, hybrid-graphics, amd-ryzen

I have a HP gaming laptop (HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-ec0001LA). The laptop has a Ryzen-3550H (with vega graphics), and a GTX1050 graphics card.

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q] (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c2)
```

I've been trying to install both graphic cards, but I couldn't. I tried with several distros (ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 20.04, Debian 10, Arch, Manjaro), and the only one who works "well" is Ubuntu 18.04. In this last distro, the Vega chip works, and I installed the Nvidia driver; however, the laptop doesn't allow me to switch between both graphic cards: Nvidia-smi command recognizes my GTX1050:

```
Fri May 22 19:52:39 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.59       Driver Version: 440.59       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  3020MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

but, nvidia-detector says I do not have any Nvidia graphic card:

```
ialtamirano@tbay:~$ nvidia-detector 
none
```

On the other hand, Ubuntu recognizes my graph just as AMD Raven
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuRHd.png

I tried to install the AMD Official drivers (amdgpu-pro), but the driver made crash my system (with no recover option, I had to reinstall all my stuff). The AMD vega chip performance is poor, really poor. Vega's performance is worst in Ubuntu than (the original installation of)Windows 10.

My question is, how could I switch between both graphic cards? Do I have a hybrid card?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked 11 months ago, but I thought I would answer anyways. From what I can find you can use `bumblebee`.

First, enable the Universe and Multiverse repositories, if you haven't already done this you need to go to `Software and Updates` and make sure these repositories are enabled. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Now install `bumblebee`, `bumblebee-nvidia`, `primus` and `linux-headers-generic` with this command: `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic`. Don't forget to reboot after this step.

After this you can run any program you want with the Nvidia card by using `optirun`, for example `optirun firefox`.

- Sources / more information: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee
- To run games on Steam with your Nvidia graphics card: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6316-GJKC-7437&l=